# httprequest fot get a file, can fail if some folder of path start by number

Tags: angular, http, get, assets, directory-structure

I have problems (404) for getting a file served by the angular assets service
I'm using the typical htpprequest (pure javascript)

```
\assets\folder\B\myfile.txt >> ok, I have the right results
\assets\folder\1\myfile.txt >> bad, error 404 : not found.
\assets\folder\2\myfile.txt >> bad, error 404 : not found.
```

I have spent some hours looking here and there but I dont found help.

The question is..
Is it the problem caused by the 'number' digit ?
Is it a problem of httprequest ?
Is it a problem of angular 14

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I identified, when considering a paths in angular, not consider only number identifiers as a string. So that to refused to find the exact destination. you can use **one** instead of **1**. If you have find any other let me know too.